# RMS Express in LMate 16.04

Tags: 14.04

Trying to get RMS Express to work with Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

Tried it through Wine but with no success. It just loaded but kept getting errors. Got rmsgw-2.4.0-182.tgz but trying to compile will take time. Is there any way to quickly compile the program for it to work or is there a wiki page with a step by step guide for this?

Comment: What is RMS Express? Where do we can download it?

Comment: Yes, compiling takes time. The How-To is usually in files named in all upper case, e.g. `INSTALL`, `README`, etc.

Comment: rmsgw → README.md → https://github.com/nwdigitalradio/rmsgw

Answer (score 0):

You can compile it with

```
sudo apt-get install xutils-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libncurses5-dev

git clone https://github.com/nwdigitalradio/rmsgw
make
sudo make install
```

After successful compilation I can launch `rmsgwmon`.

Also you can check its [INSTALLING](https://github.com/nwdigitalradio/rmsgw/blob/master/INSTALLING) file.